# ggplot2: Using `fill = …` in aes(..) and geom_bar(..). The colors don't repeat

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

My problem is that the colors form three blocks of color corresponding to the three levels of the variable Atr, instead of repeating each color. I would like that each bar is formed by as blocks as End_positions are in each chromosome. 
Actually, I have found [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920311/ggplot2-using-fill-in-aes-and-geom-bar-the-colors-repeat):

And his issue is my solution. I have tried to copy exactly his code but replacing the values but it does not work.

Also I would appreciate some suggestions in order to improve the visualization of this graph.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Chromosome, y = End_position, fill = Atr, label = End_position)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle('Stacked chromosome')
```

the table:

```
   Chromosome End_position Atr
1        chr1     35383099  PI
2        chr2      8614917  PI
3        chr2      1505317  PS
4        chr2     15804791  PI
5        chr2            1  PS
6        chr3      1299265  PI
7        chr3     22582715  PS
8        chr3      3633786  PI
9        chr3       399713  PS
10       chr3       807853  PI
```

And the current graph:

[image: Stacked Atr Barplot]

Thanks a lot, best rewards,

Daniel.

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you expect the output to look like? Maybe even a sketch/picture? What colors do you want to repeat?

Comment: Also you say "...form three blocks of color corresponding to the three levels of variable Atr" but there are only two levels of Atr in your example?

Comment: I'm also unclear. Could you clarify? To me it appears as if your Atr levels are grouped together, that is, all PI are grouped, and all PS are grouped, so the colors don't alternate, and create continuous single color bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you expecting something like the following?

*(black outline added to each component of the bars for emphasis)*

[image: plot]

Code used:

```
ggplot(df2, 
       aes(x = Chromosome, y = End_position, 
           group = seq(1, nrow(df2)), # or seq(nrow(df2), 1)
           fill = Atr, label = End_position)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle('Stacked chromosome')
```

The difference from your original code is the inclusion of `group = seq(1, nrow(df2))` in the top level aesthetics.

This forces ggplot to treat each row of the data frame as a separate group, so that rows with the same `fill` value are not grouped together in `geom_bar()`, and instead follows the row order in your data frame.

`seq(nrow(df2), 1)` would achieve the same objective, but in reverse order.